# Windows 8.1 missing WinRE.wim in WinPE

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-pe, dism

I'm trying to pull a Windows 8.1 .wim file down to a laptop (the same laptop that was the source of the .wim), and am following [these directions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825041.aspx) from MS. Everything works until "W:\Windows\System32\Recovery\winre.wim T:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim" (W:\ is what will be called C:\, when I get into Windows).

As far as I can tell, there is no winre.wim in W:\windows\system32\recovery. I ran used dir to search the W: drive, but there is no winre.wim. Where is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `winre.wim` is a file within the `install.wim` image, which should be mounted first. The mounting is carried out in Step 5:

> dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:R:\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\

In your case, as you have a W drive and prefer to mount the `install.wim` image to that location, you should have done something like:

> dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:R:\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\

PS: The answer assumes a standard `install.wim` that is equivalent to the one found on the standard installation medium. If your "Windows 8.1 .wim" is customized or created by non-standard means, then it might be really missing the `winre.wim` file. In that case, you can download the disk image from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO